# Substring Specific Word Containing Special Character between them

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring, match

I have following String

```
string test = "viv-ek is a good boy.Mah - esh is Cra - zy.";
```

I want to get `{"Vivek","Mahesh","Crazy"}` words from that string

Some having only `"-"` and some having `" - "` in between words.

Comment: If those ("-" & " - ") being the only possible cases and will not disturb the other parts, `string.Replace` and `string.Split` are good tools for you... :)

Comment: Try with `test.Replace('-', '').Replace(' - ', '')`

Comment: what is your exact question? Everyone posted their answers about replacing the character '-' in a string. If that's not the required answer, explain you question a little more.

Comment: you are right lan but i have to check those words in dictionary first then only i will decide to replace or not

Answer (score 0):

You can find your words with following regex :

```
\b\w+(?:\s-\s|-)\w+\b
```

and replace the result of match strings with `(?:\s-\s|-)` with empty string `''`.

Comment: Thank you @Kasramvd for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

```
\b\w+\s*-\s*\w+\b
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/14

Comment: `\s*-\s*` will match delimiters like  "   -".

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
string test = "viv-ek is a good boy.Mah - esh is Cra - zy.";
test = test.Replace(" -", "-").Replace("- ", "-").Replace(".", ". ");
//Or
//test = test.Replace(" - ", "-").Replace(".", ". ");
string[] allwords = test.Split(' ');
List<string> extractedWords=new List<string>();
foreach(string wrd in allwords)
{
    if(wrd.Contains("-"))
    {
        extractedWords.Add(wrd.Replace("-", ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to select those words use this:

```
string test = "viv-ek is a good boy.Mah - esh is Cra - zy.";
var words = 
    Regex
        .Matches(test, @"(?<part>\w+)(\s*-\s*(?<part>\w+))+\b")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(
            x => string.Join(
                string.Empty, 
                x.Groups["part"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().SelectMany(capture => capture.Value)))
        .ToList();
```

`words` is a list containing "vivek","Mahesh","Crazy".

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/l183Wc)

Replacing words will work the same way:

```
var replacingValues = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Crazy", "XXX" } };
var test = "viv-ek is a good boy.Mah - esh is Cra - zy.";
var replacedTest =
    Regex.Replace(
        test,
        @"\b(?<part>\w+)(\s*-\s*(?<part>\w+))+\b",
        match =>
            {
                var word = string.Join(string.Empty, match.Groups["part"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().SelectMany(capture => capture.Value));
                string replacingValue;
                return replacingValues.TryGetValue(word, out replacingValue) ? replacingValue : match.Value;
            });
```

`replacedTest`contains `viv-ek is a good boy.Mah - esh is XXX.`

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/h1Ri3g)

Comment: Thanks @Vera ring really helped

Comment: @dhiraj I added a simple sample to replace using a dictionary to check whether to do or not.